# Reference request: Tubular neighborhood theorem for non-closed manifolds via the exponential map.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $M\subset N$ be a submanifold. (Both $M$ and $N$ have no boundary, but $M\subset N$ need not to be closed as a subspace and none of them need to be compact) Choose a Riemannian metric on $N$ and identify the normal bundle $\vartheta M$ of $M$ with a subbundle of the tangent bundle of $N$ in the usual way. I'm searching for a reference with a detailed proof of the following fact:

> There exists a open neighborhood of the zero section in $\vartheta_M$, such that the exponential map of $N$ provides a diffeomorphism of the neighborhood to an open neighborhood of $N$ in $M$.

A proof is given in Lang' "Fundamentals of Differential Geometry" in the case of $N\subset M$ closed as a subset. (Theorem 5.1 on page 110) A proof sketch of the general case is given as Theorem 6.5 of da Silva's [Lectures on Symplectic Geometry](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~acannas/Books/lsg.pdf).

I searched in almost every textbook about differential geometry and topology I know, but most authors prove the theorem for compact submanifolds or at most for topological closed ones. I even began to ask myself whether the statement may actually fail in the non closed case.

Comment: Hirsch, Differential topology, ch4.5. There are no assumptions about closedness. (A 'neat submanifold' $M \subset N$ is one such that $\partial M  = M \cap \partial N$; there might be some other small condition. It's vacuous if $M$ and $N$ have empty boundary.)

Comment: He proves it by giving the surrounding manifold $N$ the induced metric from euclidian space after the choice of an embedding. I want the result for all choices of metrics. Of course this follows from the cases Hirsch examines together with the embedding theorem of Nash, but I really don't want to use the latter.

Comment: What is your definition of a submanifold? (There are several inequivalent definitions.) If all what you mean: Let $f: N\to M$ is an injective immersion, then the neighborhood does not exist.

Comment: A simple argument of the sort you're looking for is provided here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54799/on-a-proof-of-the-existence-of-tubular-neighborhoods/58124#58124